# Building uniCenta 4.2 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, openbravo

I am a novice in POS system and i am not able to start the understanding of the build that needs to be done in eclipse.Could someone help me how to make a build of uniCenta/OpenBravo in eclipse and make the application running?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look the following link to know about setting up Openbravo with eclipse:

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_setup_Eclipse_IDE

To compile the codebase go through the following link:
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Openbravo_Setup